# dropzone and jquery load method

Tags: php, jquery

I have this code for dropzone. It works. Then on complete event it has to load a php file. I am not able to pass the content of a variable. It has an id that i need to fetch data from a database. Here the code:

```
Dropzone.options.myform = {
  maxFilesize:5,
  maxFiles: 1,
  acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  previewsContainer: "#div_preview",
  dictDefaultMessage: "Premi per caricare le foto",
  params: '#hiddenId',
  init: function() {
    this.hiddenFileInput.removeAttribute('multiple');
  },
  complete: function(file) {
    var a = $("#hiddenId").val();
    alert(a);
    $('#div_preview').show();
    $("#div_preview").html("");
    $("#div_preview").load('php/load_cover_auto.php',{'id': '<?php echo $a; ?>' });
  }  
};
```

with firebug i get this reply from the server:

```
id<?php echo $a; ?>
```

I tried also to pass variable in this way but with no luck:

```
$("#div_preview").load('php/load_cover_auto.php?id=a');
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
$("#div_preview").load('php/load_cover_auto.php',{'id': '<?php echo $a; ?>'
```

Change it to:

```
$("#div_preview").load('php/load_cover_auto.php',{'id': a});
```

Because you want to get and pass the value of the jquery variable.

Comment: yes, thanks, I did it just as above and indeed it works :)

Comment: Glad you got it working :) Please accept the answer in order to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved my problem and the solution is this one:

```
$("#div_preview").load('php/load_cover_auto.php',{'id': a});
```

that's the right code!

Comment: I accepted the answer even if I was me that found the solution to my problem and my post was edited as I wrote a different thing.. is it normal? :)